# App root is not working while deploying on IIS 10

Tags: angular, iis, angular-ui-router, iis-10, angular4-router

I am new in angular 4 and developing a website. I run the code on my localhost:4200 its work fine but when i deploy on IIS 10 server its not showing any view.I thing its issue with routing . I am really strange to see that no error is showing while doing the inspect element. let me guide.Any help would be appreciated. [This is the view i am getting whiling running on local host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6L66G.png).[this is the view after deploying on IIS 10 server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPjH5.png). My Asp.Net web api is working acurately

[this is my ASp.NEt web api image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWHtQ.png).Any material could be provided any help would be appricated. I am really worried.Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue is with IIS settings.

please enable below setting from "Turn windows Features on and Off"

Internet Information services => World Wide Web Services => Common HTTP Features => **Static Content**

[image]